# invalid option when trying to curl a file in linux and give it rights for execution and then move it

Tags: linux, bash, curl, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to download  the file that will install Mate UI and give it rights to the scipt file then move it somewhere else, here is the content of the script (onpurposely one script is calling the other due to provisioning limitations):

```
sudo curl --noproxy "*" "http://location/install-gui.sh" --output /tmp/install-gui.sh

#install Mate Ui on linux
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/install-gui.sh

sudo mv /tmp/install-gui.sh /opt/

sudo /opt/install-gui.sh
```

I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   440  100   440    0     0   2430      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2430
: invalid option
```

Comment: sudo curl --noproxy "*" "http://location/install-gui.sh" --output /tmp/install-gui.sh

sudo chmod 777 /tmp/install-gui.sh

sudo mv /tmp/install-gui.sh /opt/

sudo /opt/install-gui.sh

Comment: That error message looks like something I'd expect from having DOS/Windows-style line endings in your script. Do the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) solve the problem?